# Group a DataFrame by months and an additional column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the next DataFrame:

```
data={
 'date':['02/01/2023', '03/01/2023', '12/01/2023', '16/01/2023', '23/01/2023', '03/02/2023', '14/02/2023', '17/02/2023', '17/02/2023', '20/02/2023'],
'amount':[-2.6, -230.0, -9.32, -13.99, -12.99, -50.0, -5.84, -6.6, -11.95, -20.4],
'concept':['FOOD', 'REPAIR', 'HEALTH', 'NO CLASSIFIED', 'NO CLASSIFIED', 'REPAIR', 'FOOD', 'NO CLASSIFIED', 'FOOD', 'HEALTH']     
      }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to group the information first by months and then by the concept of each item. I tried something this:

```
df.groupby(['date','concept']).sum()
```

And it works for an individual day, but I need the same but grouped by the entire month.

I tried also converting that `df.date` to datetime values: `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date,dayfirst=True)`, but I don't know how to indicate that the grouping should be by the each entire month.

The result I need would be something like this:

| date | concept | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-23 | FOOD | -2.6 |
|  | HEALTH | -9.32 |
|  | NO CLASSIFIED | -26.98 |
|  | REPAIR | -230 |
| Feb-23 | FOOD | -17.79 |
|  | HEALTH | -20.4 |
|  | NO CLASSIFIED | -6.6 |
|  | REPAIR | -50 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datetime module. First convert the date column to a datetime object and then create new year and month columns accessing by 'dt'. Then groupby and sum. try below code:

```
import datetime

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"],dayfirst=True)
df["month"] = df["date"].dt.month
df["year"] = df["date"].dt.year
df.drop("date",axis=1,inplace = True)

result = df.groupby(["year","month","concept"]).sum()
```

or you can use :

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"],dayfirst=True)
df['month_year'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('M')
df.drop("date",axis=1,inplace = True)
result = df.groupby(["month_year","concept"]).sum()
```

Comment: It works, but how could I do it so I don't have year-month for each row but just year-month and then all the concepts and then the next year-month and the subsequent concepts (similar as I put it on the table in the question)

Comment: is the second option an exact solution for you ?

Comment: Need to use `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], dayfirst = True)` to avoid potential confusion with dates

Comment: @UgurYigit that is. It works as expected but I should put previously the line commented `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date,dayfirst=True)`